# Zend framework 1 submit form url / action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm working on a AJAX sign up form which will be submitted to the Zend Framework.  Right now, the form's action doesn't seem to be executing.  The response text is a duplicate of the current HTML document.  Can someone please inform me of what I'm doing wrong, and what the correct URL should be?  I've set the project up using modules.  For example, should the correct url from the example below be: '/account/register/auth'

```
#application.ini
resources.router.routes.register.route = /register
resources.router.routes.register.defaults.module = account
resources.router.routes.register.defaults.controller = register
resources.router.routes.register.defaults.action = index

#application/modules/accout/controllers/RegisterController.php
<?php
    class Account_RegisterController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
        public function init(){
            $this->view->register = new Account_Form_Register();
        }

        public function indexAction(){

        }

        public function authAction(){
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            $form = new Account_Form_Register();

            if($request->isPost()){
                print('submit');
            }else{
                print('nothing yet');
            }
        }
    }
?>

#application/modules/account/views/scripts/register/index.phtml
<div class="register">
        <form id="registerForm">
            <h2 class="formHeader">Register</h2>

            <div class="floatLeft">
                <?php echo $this->register->fName; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="remaining">
                <?php echo $this->register->lName; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="floatLeft">
                <?php echo $this->register->uEmail; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="remaining">
                <?php echo $this->register->aEmail; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="">
                <?php echo $this->register->phone; ?>
            </div>

            <div class="floatLeft">
                <?php echo $this->register->oPassword; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="remaining">
                <?php echo $this->register->cPassword; ?>
            </div>

            <div id="formButton">
                <?php echo $this->register->submit; ?>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: May be you should disable the view processing when you are doing ajax action (because you are using an echo such as `echo json_encode($some_data);` and you don't want to return anything else.

Comment: Changing the form to a non-AJAX post has the same outcome.

Comment: can you give us your HTML code .? In general, URL should be like http://your_site/your_controller/your_action and you can have just after some GET param like `?var=value` or `/value` depending on your configuration.

Comment: Add HTML to original post.

Comment: I managed to get the form to submit, but correct action will not execute.  Does every action require a corresponding .phtml file?  Right now with the url of mysite/account/register/authenticate returns a 500 error because authenticate.phtml cannot be found.

Answer (score -1):

As I said, maybe you should disable the view processing when doing AJAX action in order to return a `json_encode($some_data)` instead of HTML content.

Try

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

Take a look at [this article](http://www.luscarpa.com/snippets/zend-framework/disable-layout-and-view-render/)

Comment: I do not think he is referring that his view is not being rendered or he is having problem with view. He seems to be unable to execute the action with normal http call as well (not involving ajax requests); his problem is possibly related to  route as mentioned in question.

Comment: Trying to find a solution. Indeed, the view don't seems to be the direct problem but it could be a futur problem as he is using a ajax process. find a solution instead of voting down...